# Android Studio Emulator displays white screen

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I have created an Android application with Android Studio which was compiling and running fine.
I had to switch laptops recently, and when I open the same project on the new laptop it compiles, but the screen of the app in the emulator remains white, just like an empty project.

I have tried to use the same Virtual Device as before, as i thought it could be some android version incompatibility but it didn't work.